# Jetpack JSON API configure button not showing

Tags: api, json, plugin-jetpack

Installed fresh WP on my Hostgator - shared host plan.
Installed Jetpack, connected to wordpress but can't make the JSON API to work. After activating there's no Configure button just deactivate button and i'm stuck. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything. As soon as you connect Jetpack to your WordPress.com account and activate the JSON API module, you'll be able to to use the API. You can double check that by running some test queries using [the REST API Console here](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/). You could also just try to load one of the endpoints in your browser, [like so](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/jetpack.me/posts/).

If you're still having issues working with Jetpack's REST API, I'd suggest [contacting the Jetpack support team through this form](http://jetpack.me/contact-support/), or [in the Jetpack support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/jetpack). As mentioned in [on-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's best to use appropriate support channels for third party plugins and themes.

Comment: yes thank you, i was following tutorial and i realized tutorial was using the old jetpack which had configure button.